# Force reload the browser when pressing F5 or refresh button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm developing an web application using ASP.NET and C#..

I'm facing an issue, that when I press "F5" or "refresh button", after changing value in dropdown list, it changes back to first value..

But if I press "Ctrl+F5", the dropdown list is not changing..

After analysis I found Ctrl+F5 is doing force reload..

So now I want to do same thing when I press F5 or refresh button or Ctrl+R also..

How to do that..? I need to identify which browser also.. Because this happen only in Firefox..

Also, where (which event) I've to do that coding..?

Comment: If you hit F5 or refresh button you're doing a reload of the page which isn't the same as a postback so your dropdown will go to default value. I'm not sure why Ctrl+F5 isn't doing the same thing, that should be a full refresh.

Comment: I'm also not clear on why you would want to keep a value when pressing F5 anyway, can you give some context?

Comment: @owen79, I'm using it in a report page.. So it has to keep that value until I press save button.. Other values or in label form, so the can't be able to change..

Comment: SSRS allows this (change params -> update report -> change params -> update report), no need to reinvent the wheel to provide reports

Comment: @Alex, in report its updating.. There's no issue in it.. The issue in in this page alone.. If I hit refresh before save button, it changes back to default value..

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve this issue is to save the selected value of your drop-down list into the [web storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) using the [onunload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) (or `onbeforeunload`) event in Javascript.

Then, you just have to get it back **after** the page loading using the [onload](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) event.

**EDIT - sample code**

So, here is your dropdown list :

```
<select id="list">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Now, let's see the Js :

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.document.getElementById('list').selectedIndex = localStorage['mySavedValue'];
};

window.onunload = function() {
    localStorage['mySavedValue'] = window.document.getElementById('list').selectedIndex;
};
```

I tested it on a local page on firefox 26.0 (linux) and it worked. See working jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ngVGC/)

Comment: Can u post sample coding..?

Comment: Did you tried the jsFiddle ? If so, can you see mySavedValue into the localstorage using firebug ?

Comment: Sorry, can't try in jsFiddle.. Cause, when I hit F5 or refresh, it asks for "Leave the page or Stay on page".. If I select "Leave" means, whole things reloaded.. So I've to run it again from first.. If I select "Stay on page" measn, its not reloading..

Comment: I don't have this behavior into jsFiddle. But nevermind, you've got 2 choices : first, you hit the run button after selecting a value (different of 'A' preferably) in order to simulate page refresh, or you can click the "Leave" button after hitting F5, this should work also.

Comment: Yeah, I done same thing.. But after refresh, I've click run.. Then only the dropdown control comes visible..

Comment: It's just a sample code where there is just one dropdown list. Just land on the page, change the value in the list, hit run or F5 and see that the value you had selected is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. this will treat F5 and Ctrl+F5 in same way....

```
<script language="javascript" >
var ctrl = false;
document.onkeydown = function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 17) {
        ctrl = true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 116 && ctrl == true) {
        //alert("ctrl+f5");
        window.location.relord();
        ctrl = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 116 && ctrl == false) {
        window.location.relord();
        //alert("f5");
    }

}
```